# warning glob() expects parameter 2 to be to long

Tags: php, jquery, gallery

When I navigate to the gallery page on my website, above where the album thumbnail picture is there is the error message that I will type below.

```
warning glob() expects parameter 2 to be to long, string blah blah blah on line 237
```

I'm using FolioGallery version 2.0.
http://www.foliopages.com/php-jquery-ajax-photo-gallery-no-database

FolioGallery.php
http://pastebin.com/R77yYBuA

I'm not sure what version of PHP my host is using, but on my local web hosting machine that I use to locally test my website it works fine. I'm sure that my local host PHP version is newer than my hosts PHP version. Is there any way to get this to work on the older PHP version?

This is what I'm using to call the FolioGallery

```
            <!-- Start Gallery -->
            <div class="php-gallery">
            <?php include('foliogallery-demo2.php'); ?>
            </div>
            <!-- End Gallery -->
```

FolioGallery-demo2.php 
http://pastebin.com/vka1zJiA

The scripts and other related files can be downloaded from the FolioGallery link which I provided above.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php): Note: The GLOB_BRACE flag is not available on some non GNU systems, like Solaris.

Comment: Is that what you were asking for? I'm checking with my provider what type of system they use right now as well. Are there any other PHP gallerys like this that you might recommend if this doesn't work?

Comment: Your question is about code you downloaded, not code that you've written yourself? You should contact the author of that code if you have issues with it.

Comment: I haven't been able to find a place to do that which is why I came here. I guess I was just seeing if there was a way to get the GLOB flag to variable to work with a PHP version under 5.0.

Comment: PHP version less than 5.0? That's seriously old.

Comment: So I found out that its 5.4.23 that is running. So its no the PHP version.
The host specialist that I was talking to said the quote below.
"It is Solaris, but mostly things are compiled against local libraries, so that probably doesn't matter as much as it might." When I asked if the system they used was Solaris cause I was asking about the GLOB flag.

Comment: He also asked, "But this looks like you have a problem in the PHP code.  It says the glob() function got called with a string (text) instead of a long (number) as the second argument.  Is that code you wrote?".
I pointed him to the foliogallery page because that is not code that I wrote. Everything does run fine on my local machine though which I also pointed out to him.

Comment: Since
    $thumb_pool = glob($mainFolder.'/'.$albums[$i].'/thumbs/*{.'.implode(",", $extensions).'}', GLOB_BRACE); 
is the code in question, is it possible to loop on $extensions and solve this issue that way? How would you go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

`$thumb_pool = glob($mainFolder.'/'.$albums[$i].'/thumbs/*{.'.implode(",",$extensions).'}', GLOB_BRACE);`

With

```
//$thumb_pool = glob($mainFolder.'/'.$albums[$i].'/thumbs/*{.'.implode(",",$extensions).'}', GLOB_BRACE);

$thumb_pool = glob($mainFolder.'/'.$albums[$i].'/thumbs/*.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop instead of braces:

```
$thumb_pool = array();
foreach ($extensions as $ext) {
    $temp = glob($mainFolder.'/'.$albums[$i].'/thumbs/*'.$ext);
    $thumb_pool = array_merge($thumb_pool, $temp);
}
```